# Rotate objects in the corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my game there are two objects (eyes) and I need to make them turn in the direction where the screen was clicked.I found an example listener on the Internet, but it's for multitouch, and I need onetouch.

```
system.activate("multitouch")

local touches = {}
local touchIDs = {}

local function detectMultitouch()
    for i = 1, #touchIDs do
        print("#"..i.." "..tostring(touchIDs[i]) .." = "..touches[touchIDs[i]].x..","..touches[touchIDs[i]].y)
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",function(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        touches[event.id] = {}
        touches[event.id].x = event.x
        touches[event.id].y = event.y
        touches[event.id].coords = display.newText(tostring(event.id).." = "..touches[event.id].x..","..touches[event.id].y,0,0,system.nativeFont,15)
        touches[event.id].coords.x = touches[event.id].x
        touches[event.id].coords.y = touches[event.id].y

        table.insert(touchIDs,event.id)
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        touches[event.id].x = event.x
        touches[event.id].y = event.y
        touches[event.id].coords.text = tostring(event.id).." = "..touches[event.id].x..","..touches[event.id].y
        touches[event.id].coords.x = touches[event.id].x
        touches[event.id].coords.y = touches[event.id].y - 20
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        touches[event.id].coords:removeSelf()
        touches[event.id] = nil
        table.remove(touchIDs,table.indexOf(touchIDs, event.id))


        detectMultitouch(touches)
    end
end)
```

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `event.x` and `event.y` to get the touch coordinates. Then you could compare them with the eyes coordinates.

This said it is necessary to have 2 different objects for the white part and the coloured part (sorry I don't know the specific names).

This way the white part stands still and you modify the x and y of the coloured part by specific numbers. These numbers would be different depending on the information you got before.